# How to press a button with selenium and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I need to press a button from a webpage with selenium,but that button has no id.
Other buttons from same webpage are having an id so no problem with pressing that ones with following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('some_id').click()
```

When i use firebug and firepath on that problem button output is:

```
<span class="linkRosso"> Invia truppe</span>
```

xpath:

```
html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[3]/span
```

Is this information useful??

Comment: The xpath you have used will break if a the html changes a bit. If you can post the html then I can help you write an xpath which will not break very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [find_element_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath).

```
xpath = 'html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[3]/span'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Comment: yeah that worked!thx;) But next thing is,after pressing the button it is going on another page.And then i can't interact with page anymore.Got a solution for that falsetru?Do i have to follow the new link somehow?